# Sliding window with selective repeat

Tags: sliding-window

With max sequence = 7

Suppose machine A sends frame 0,1,2,3 to machine B.

B receives 0,1,3 from A(frame 2 is lost or damaged)

Will B advance it's receiving window to 2,3,4,5 or still remains in 0,1,2,3?

Answer (score 1):

It would be `2,3,4,5`, since as `0,1` are received, it moves the sliding window by two. But since `2` is lost, it would remain at the same position.

Answer (score 0):

the sliding in selective repeat depends on the received ack's for the previous frame and it should be consecutive . b sends ack's for 0 1 3 then o and 1 are consecutive it will move the sliding window till it gets any unacknowledged frame . it will wait for the time out for this frame (2) and resend it after timeout. meanwhile as  b sent ack for 3 also it will mark it as acknowledged but will not move.